MediaElementSource Node - Waveform Visualizer not rendering on Safari
I'm working on a waveform visualization for a React project I'm building. To start, I copied the code from this tutorial. Then, because my source is going to (eventually) be a web stream, which has a static url, I pointed the <audio> source to a local file.
Basically, the visualizer works for Chrome and Firefox, but the canvas element stays blank on Safari, even though there are no errors in the console.
With the original code, I was getting the error
Media element is already associated with an audio source node, in Safari only.
so I changed the analyzer to check for already-created nodes/contexts:

let source;
let audioCtx;
let analyzer;

const audioAnalyzer = () => {
        if (!audioCtx) {
            audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        }
        if (!analyzer) {
            analyzer = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
        }
        analyzer.fftSize = 2048;

        const bufferLength = analyzer.frequencyBinCount;
        const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
        if (!source) {
            source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElmRef.current);
        }
        source.connect(analyzer);
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        source.onended = () => {
            source.disconnect();
        };
        setAnalyzerData({analyzer, bufferLength, dataArray});
    };

Now that error is gone in Safari (& all other browsers), but the waveform still doesn't render in Safari.
I have made waveform visualizations that work on Safari for really basic projects (that don't use React), so I'm wondering if this issue is caused by the framework. I'm new to React, so I'm not sure. Has anyone run into this? How can I fix it?
